# Python: Selenium with PhantomJS empty page source

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm having trouble with Selenium and PhantomJS on Windows7 when I want to get the source of the page of an URL.
`browser.page_source` returns only `<html><head></head></html>`. I've put a sleep before `browser.page_source` but it didn't help.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs.exe')
url = 'myurl'
browser.get(url)
print browser.page_source
```

On Linux with the same version of PhantomJS it works perfectly. Also it works on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Try some debugging, capture a screenshot for example

Comment: The screenshot is empty, blank image.

I thought that it's a problem with PhantomJS and I've tried to load the page with PyQt4's webkit but the result is the same, just <html> and <head> tags.
This is the URL which gives me this headache: https://www.homesearch.com/browse?fulltextquery=miami+fl&page=0

Comment: I've encountered the same issue when navigated to some _https_://url. Use `time.sleep(few_seconds)` or webdriver's [expected conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) to wait for some element to be present on page after calling `browser.get(url)`

Comment: also try to creat a driver instance with these params `browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs.exe', service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])`

Comment: I've used a sleep of 15-20 seconds and the result was the same. I will try with service_args.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

by default phantomjs use SSLv3, but many sites after bug in ssl migrate to tls. That's why you has blank page. 
use `service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any']`

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs.exe', service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])
```

Comment: Upvoted this because using just the ignore ssl error did not work for me but adding ssl protocol any suggested by this comment help. Kudos

Comment: Be aware that `--ignore-ssl-errors` is dangerous and you shouldn't use it unless you know what you're doing. The other option will probably fix most issues.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me allot of time.

Comment: @AlexW this solution is worked for me, but I don't know under the hood about this. Could you elaborate about the dangerous using `--ignore-ssl-errors` or provide some reference about this?

Comment: I have a related question: `How can we found these selenium phantomjs usages?` I think it's very hard for me to find these usages in http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/

Answer (score 8):

Using `service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true']` did the trick !

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs.exe', service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
```

Comment: I am using `webdriver.Remote` as I am running a phantomJS remotely. Do you know how to pass the service_args if this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

```
driverPhantom = webdriver.PhantomJS(driverLocation, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])      # initaling web driver for PhantomJs
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

increasing the screen size as below worked for me:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(path2phantom, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any']) 
driver.set_window_size(2000, 1500)
```