# Phantomjs prints empty HTML source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phantomjs

I have a JS file to add headers as follows.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var system = require('system');
var page = webPage.create();

page.customHeaders = {"pragma": "akamai-x-feo-trace"};
page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Try to pass some args when invoking this script!');
} else {
    page.open(system.args[1], function (status) {
    var content = page.content;
    console.log(content);
    phantom.exit();
    });
}
```

I am now executing the following phantoms command

`phantomjs RequestURL.js http:////www.ubank.com.au > body.html`

Upon opening `body.html` I get an empty HTML file as follows.

`<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Why the HTML source is not getting generated here.

Comment: try using service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'].see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581291/python-selenium-with-phantomjs-empty-page-source

Comment: I tried now `phantomjs RequestURL.js service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'] http:////www.ubank.com.au > body.html` still empty html

Comment: `http:////www.ubank.com.au` is definitely not a valid URL. Try ``http://www.ubank.com.au``

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Maybe page content is not loading with DOM start. (I had the same problem). You can set any timeout after load page.

**2.** Don't use `page.content` function. Better write simple execute in client-side. Like that:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.body.outerHTML;
})
```

Or, something like that. If you have any JS errors, please comment my post with this errors. Hope, its help