# Failing to open HTTPS pages in PhantomJS using Splinter

Tags: python, https, phantomjs, splinter

I'm trying to use PhantomJS to write a scraper but even the example in the documentation of morph.io is not working. I guess the problem is "https", I tested it with http and it is working. Can you please give me a solution? 
I tested it using firefox and it works.

```
from splinter import Browser

with Browser("phantomjs") as browser:
    # Optional, but make sure large enough that responsive pages don't
    # hide elements on you...
    browser.driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)

    # Open the page you want...
    browser.visit("https://morph.io")

    # submit the search form...
    browser.fill("q", "parliament")
    button = browser.find_by_css("button[type='submit']")
    button.click()

    # Scrape the data you like...
    links = browser.find_by_css(".search-results .list-group-item")
    for link in links:
        print link['href']
```

PhantomJS is not working on https urls?

Comment: Have you tried starting PhantomJS with the --ignore-ssl-errors=yes option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Splinter uses the Selenium WebDriver bindings ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24385267)) for Python under the hood, so you can simply pass the necessary options like this:

```
with Browser("phantomjs", service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any']) as browser:
    ...
```

See [PhantomJS failing to open HTTPS site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12021578/1816580) for why those options might be necessary. Take a look at the [PhantomJS commandline interface](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) for more options.