# Getting results of Google Scholar search with selenium and PhantomJS

Tags: selenium, web, phantomjs

The following code is supposed to print the contents of [this](https://scholar.google.co.il/scholar?q=The%20Trellis%20Security%20Infrastructure:%20%7BA%7D%20Layered%20Approach%20to%20Overlay%20Metacomputers) page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
link = u'https://scholar.google.co.il/scholar?q=The+Trellis+Security+Infrastructure:+{A}+Layered+Approach+to+Overlay+Metacomputers'
driver.get(link)
print driver.page_source
```

However, all it prints is:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

If I use `webdriver.Firefox()` instead of `webdriver.PhantomJS()`, it works. I know that `PhantomJS` is properly installed, since the above code used to work just fine. What could this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Selenium/PhantomJs are you using? 
I tried with:

- Selenium 3.6.0
- PhantomJs 2.1.1

this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'PathTo/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs')
link = 'https://scholar.google.co.il/scholar?q=The+Trellis+Security+Infrastructure:+{A}+Layered+Approach+to+Overlay+Metacomputers'
driver.get(link)
print (driver.page_source)
```

and it works.

Comment: Found the solution! https://stackoverflow.com/a/34257642/2725810 Accepting this answer as it led me to solve the problem.